# .json pretrained model using in matlab

Tags: matlab

i download pretrained model from this url: https://tfhub.dev/mediapipe/tfjs-model/handpose_3d/detector/full/1?tfjs-format=compressed and now i have two files: 1)model.json 2)group1-shard1of1.bin how can i use this pretrined model in matlab or convert this pretrained model to .h5 model

i download pretrained model from this url: https://tfhub.dev/mediapipe/tfjs-model/handpose_3d/detector/full/1?tfjs-format=compressed and now i have two files: 1)model.json 2)group1-shard1of1.bin how can i use this pretrined model in matlab or convert this pretrained model to .h5 model

how can i use in matlab